# RSS reader openStream()

Tags: java, rss, rss-reader

I am new to Java , but really want to become better at it. I'm trying to write a simple RSS reader. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RSSReader {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(readRSS("http://www.usnews.com/rss/health-news"));
}
public static String readRSS(String urlAddress){
    try {
            URL rssUrl = new URL(urlAddress);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rssUrl.openStream()));
            String sourceCode = "";
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine())!=null){
                if(line.contains("<title>")){
                    int firstPos = line.indexOf("<title>");
                    String temp = line.substring(firstPos);
                    temp = temp.replace("<title>","");
                    int lastPos = temp.indexOf("</title>");
                    temp = temp.substring(0,lastPos);
                    sourceCode +=temp+"\n";
                }
            }
        System.out.println("YAAAH"+sourceCode);
        in.close();

        return sourceCode;
    }   catch (MalformedURLException ue) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL");
    }   catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("WTF?");
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

But it is catching IOException all the time, and I see "WTF".
I realised that the whole program fails when `OpenStream()` starts its' work.
I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Hmmm , yes. I am behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated, you would need to set your *proxy parameters/credentials* right before you establish a connection.

Set proxy `username` and `password` **only** in case your proxy is authenticated.

```
public static String readRSS(String urlAddress) {

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", YOUR_PROXY_HOST);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", YOUR_PROXY_PORT);

//Below 2 for authenticated proxies only
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", YOUR_USERNAME);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", YOUR_PASSWORD);

 try {
    ...
```

I tested your method behind a proxy and it works perfectly, after setting the parameters i.e.